# How to set the PMD in RSA 7.5.5.3?

Tags: java, code-analysis, rad

I have the RSA (Rational Software Architect) 7.5.5.3 and i implemented the findbugs in my IDE. But i need to implement the PMD in my RSA. So please tell me the procedure or way to implement this to my RSA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this link](http://sourceforge.net/p/pmd/discussion/188192/thread/61031804#6a03), you need to use a release of the PMD for Eclipse plugin that corresponds to the Eclipse version your RSA version is based on.  According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Rational_Software_Architect#IBM_Rational_Software_Architect_Versions), that is Eclipse 3.6 *aka* Helios.

Apart from that ... it is just a plugin, so you should be able to install it like other Eclipse plugins.

---

**UPDATE** - I just noticed that you mentioned two different versions of RSA.  Check the 2nd link to find the correspondence for the version you are *actually* using.